# Visual Studio SQL query not working

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I have a problem with a SQL query. The problem is with the `IN ....`, but I don't know how to correct it. This is the query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Reports, Games, Developers
WHERE Game = SpelID
  AND Developer = IDDvl
  AND Land IN[‘Japan’,‘USA’,‘UK’,‘Indië’,‘Duitsland’,‘Zweden’]
```

This is the error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
    occurred in System.Data.dll

In operator without () in query expression 'Game = SpelID AND Developer = IDDvl
    AND Land IN [‘Japan’, ‘USA’, ‘UK’, ‘Indië’, ‘Duitsland’, ‘Zweden’]'.
```

Comment: When you say there's an error message, people are going to ask you what the error message was, but I see in your edit history that you've removed it. I'm adding it back in right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    dagoederen = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Reports , Games, 
Developers WHERE Game = SpelID AND Developer = IDDvl AND Land IN (‘Japan’, 
‘USA’, ‘UK’, ‘Indië’, ‘Duitsland’, ‘Zweden’)", connectie)
```

You need to replace `[ ]` with `()` after `IN`

Answer (score 0):

Use right brackets and quotes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Reports , Games, Developers 
WHERE Game = SpelID AND 
      Developer = IDDvl AND 
      Land IN ('Japan', 'USA', 'UK', 'Indië', 'Duitsland', 'Zweden')
```

Comment: Thanks this works! Vote up this!

Answer (score 0):

replace with this code

```
 Imports System.Data.OleDb
 Public Class Form1
 Private Sub cmdsql1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsql1.Click
connectie.Open()

Dim dagoederen As Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
 dagoederen = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Reports , Games, Developers WHERE Game = SpelID AND Developer = IDDvl AND Land IN (‘Japan’, ‘USA’, ‘UK’, ‘Indië’, ‘Duitsland’, ‘Zweden’)", connectie)

 Dim dtgoederen As DataSet = New DataSet
 dagoederen.Fill(dtgoederen, "Reports")
 connectie.Close()

 dggoederen.DataSource = dtgoederen.Tables("Reports")
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is specified in the error provided" In operator without () in query expression". Replace the "[]" with "()" for the IN T-SQL

Comment: Now i have this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in string in query expression 'Game = SpelID AND Developer = IDDvl AND Land IN (‘Japan’, 'USA’, ‘UK’, ‘Indië’, ‘Duitsland’, ‘Zweden’)'.

Comment: You have 'Games' in the select part and 'Game' in the where part of the query. Is that a mistake?  Also what is the datatype of SpellID and IDDvl that you are passing? Did you try and run the query by itself against the database first and check if it comes up with a result rather than running it in VB.Net?

Comment: I had misspelling, the names was not the same as country names was in database.

Of course this is case sensitive.(Duitsland != Germany) => for sql not :);

Thanks everyone. This works good.